# android studio trying to return to main activity error in my code

Tags: java, android-studio

I had no trouble going from my MainActivity class to my TimeIn class, but im having problems getting back to the main activity, here's my Java class file TimeIn :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class TimeIn extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.timeinlayout);
    final Globals g = (Globals)getApplication();
    final int timestart=g.getData1();
    final ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public int i = 0;

        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (i == 0 && timestart == 0) {
                btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.lgbtn1);
                g.setData1(1);
                i = 1;
            }
            if (i == 0 && timestart == 1) {
                btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.lgbtn);
                g.setData1(0);
                i = 1;
            }
            Intent punch2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(punch2);
        }
    });
    final ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public int j = 0;
        Globals g = (Globals) getApplication();
        final int breakstart = g.getData2();

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (j == 0 && breakstart == 0) {
                btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.lgbtn3);
                g.setData2(1);
                j = 1;
            }
            if (j == 0 && breakstart == 1) {
                btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.lgbtn2);
                g.setData2(0);
                j = 1;
            }
            Intent punch3 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(punch3);
        }
    });
}
}
```

it won't compile this way and the code error says:
Cannot resolve constructor 'intent(Java. lang. Class < com.package.appname >)'

But if I move both intents after their respective ends like this:

```
//previous onClick 1st codeblock
});
Intent punch2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(punch2);
//previous onClick 2nd codeblock
});
Intent punch3 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(punch3);
}
}
```

it works, but immediatly goes back to the main activity, I want to be able to click btn1 or btn2 first, which should be fired from the on click method i would think, and then to return to the MainActivity. I'm fairly new at Java, any help would be appreciated, it's probably something simple i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what i did wrong, I had to split that code up, so i defined the intent in the onCreate method, like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class TimeIn extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.timeinlayout);
        final Globals g = (Globals) getApplication();
        final int timestart = g.getData1();
        final int breakstart = g.getData2();

        final Intent punch2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);/* this is where i defined the intent, and you have to declair it as final*/

        final ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        if (timestart == 0){btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.lgbtn);}
        if (timestart == 1){btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.lgbtn1);}
        if (breakstart == 0){btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.lgbtn2);}
        if (breakstart == 1){btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.lgbtn3);}
```

and then used the second half inside each onClick method like this:

```
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public int i = 0;

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (i == 0 && timestart == 0) {
                    btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.lgbtn1);
                    g.setData1(1);
                    i = 1;
                }
                if (i == 0 && timestart == 1) {
                    btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.lgbtn);
                    g.setData1(0);
                    i = 1;
                }
                startActivity(punch2);//starts the new activity after button click tasks
                return;
            }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public int j = 0;
            Globals g = (Globals) getApplication();


            public void onClick(View v) {
                final ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
                if (j == 0 && breakstart == 0) {
                    btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.lgbtn3);
                    g.setData2(1);
                    j = 1;
                }
                if (j == 0 && breakstart == 1) {
                    btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.lgbtn2);
                    g.setData2(0);
                    j = 1;
                }
                startActivity(punch2);
                return;
            }
        });


    }

}
```

So it turns out it was my fault so I hope this helps someone else starting out learning Java